# Pass parameter from java class to jsp using ActionRequest Actionresponse

Tags: java, jsp, liferay-6, request-object

I have a function say :

```
 public void display(ActionRequest areq, ActionResponse ares) throws Exception,PortletException,IOException {

 String name= areq.getParameter("name");
 String add= areq.getParameter("add");
 String phone= areq.getParameter("phone");
}
```

I have a jsp say disp.jsp which passes the user input to the above function display.
Now I after doing some processing on the above data in display() function, I want to display the results on a jsp page say new.jsp. How should I go ahead with it?
I tried something like:

```
areq.setAttribute("name",name);
areq.getRequestDispatcher("new.jsp").forward(areq, aresp); but it shows an error that getRequestDispatcher is not defined for actionrequest and actionresponse.
```

I am using liferay framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your action you can set attributes and set the redirect page like that:

```
public void display(ActionRequest aReq, ActionResponse aResp){


    aReq.setAttribute("name",name);

    aResp.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/new.jsp");
}
```

I Usually prefer setting attributes instead of Parameters, because it allows to pass non Sting variables.
Then, in the jsp you can get the attributes

```
<%
String name = (String)renderRequest.getAttribute("name");   
%>
```

Just remember to include this, to have access to renderRequest object

```
<portlet:defineObjects />
```

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. Your solution works. I have accepted your answer. Thanks again. You'd helped in another forum here... :)

Comment: Nice, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: :) by the way, is there any way here on SO to connect with people?

Comment: Please help me with the following if you can:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102205/access-values-displayed-in-search-container-in-another-jsp